# When I made a do/while loop in C++ in order to allow a player to play the game again, the game only loops once, how do I fix this?

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

```
char playAgain;
do
{
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
    random_shuffle(words.begin(), words.end());
    const string THE_WORD = words[0];   //word to guess
    int wrong = 0;                      //number of incorrect guesses
    string soFar(THE_WORD.size(), '-'); //word guessed so far
    string used = "";                   //letter alrdy guessed

    cout << "Welcome to Hangman. Good luck!\n";

    while ((wrong < MAX_WRONG) && (soFar != THE_WORD))
    {
        cout << "\n\nYou have " << (MAX_WRONG - wrong);
        cout << " incorrect guesses left.\n";
        cout << "\nYou've used the following letters:\n" << used << endl;
        cout << "\nSo far, the word is:\n" << soFar << endl;

        char guess;
        cout << "\n\nEnter you guess: ";
        cin >> guess;
        guess = toupper(guess);  //make uppercase since secret word in uppercase
        while (used.find(guess) != string::npos)
        {
            cout << "You've already guessed " << guess << endl;
            cout << "Enter you guess: ";
            cin >> guess;
            guess = toupper(guess);
        }

        used += guess;

        if (THE_WORD.find(guess) != string::npos)
        {
            cout << "That's right! " << guess << " is in the word.\n";

            //update soFar to include newly guessed letter
            for (int i = 0; i < THE_WORD.length(); ++i)
            {
                if (THE_WORD[i] == guess)
                {
                    soFar[i] = guess;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Sorry, " << guess << " isn't in the word.\n";
            ++wrong;
        }
    }

    //shut down
    if (wrong == MAX_WRONG)
    {
        cout << "\nYou've been hanged!";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\nYou guessed it!";
    }

    cout << "\nThe word was " << THE_WORD << endl;
    cout << "\nPlay again? < Y , N >\n";
    cin >> playAgain;
} while ((playAgain == 'Y') || (playAgain == 'y'));
return 0;
```

Hello, I have tried to make this game be a game which can be repeatable. I succeeded, but noticed that the game only loops once when the player selects either Y or y. This is obviously because playAgain now retains that value. How do I fix this so that playAgain "forgets" what the user input when the game begins again? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Unrelated: `srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));` should only be executed _once_ - move it before the loop, right at the beginning of the program.

Comment: Note: `random_shuffle` was deprecated in C++14 and removed in C++17. Use `shuffle` instead. Also, please make a [mcve].

Comment: `playAgain = 'n';` at the top of the loop? Reading a single `char` is horribly fragile and will fail if additional extraneous characters are present (like entering `"yes"` instead of `'y'`) Consider [std::basic_istream::ignore](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) following each input. There isn't anything overtly wrong with your input.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, I've just started learning C++ about a month ago by myself with a book that apparently is a bit dated. I will probably continue to finish the book to understand the concepts and move on to modern online tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I see that the loop won't work is if you have characters in the buffer that you haven't read yet, so clear the line with `cin.ignore()`. You need to `#include <limits>` for this to work:

```
    ...
    cout << "\nPlay again? < Y , N >\n";
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    if(!(cin >> playAgain)) break; // if extraction fails, we're probably at EOF
) while(...);
```

Comment: I'd also scold about validation, e.g. `if (!(std::cin >> playAgain)) break;`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Good idea, added.